# Gerrit permission to review a specific path

Tags: permissions, gerrit

Im currently working on a big project with more then one team.

Lets say in the project there are some modules that each team working on.

In addition we are using gerrit for sometime now and there is something i couldn't find out.

My question is the following:
Is there a way to tell Gerrit that only specific people/group(on Gerrit) will have permission to review code (+2) on specific path/module on the project?

Comment: Why would you do this? It's only beneficial to get an external perspective to your code. You **cannot** reasonably deny teams working on the same project the read-access to the codebase of the project. That only slows them down, and again: For a codereview a pair of eyes not used to the "normal madness" is almost always a good idea

Comment: We are using 2 steps of code review: +1 and +2. Only when a new code gets +2 it allowed to be submited. Thats why we want to give the +2 permision of specific module only to the group that know it the best

Comment: @liranG Isn't this the kind of thing that would be more easily done with an email/policy meeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, and can be achieved by using the Gerrit OWNERS Plugin. I haven't configured this plugin myself, but we use this in our codebase to protect certain areas of code.

Every folder that needs protection contains a file named OWNERS that has the following structure.

```
inherited: true
owners:
- user-a@example.com
- user-b@example.com
```

Here is the link to a readme for the plugin. Hope you can figure out how to configure it.

https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/owners/+/refs/heads/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by making two separate commits. You can later add the group that you want to review the code on that specific path using gerrit interface.